# How to access ons-carousel variable in Angular Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I would like to bind an eventhandler to my ons-carousel postchange event in my AngularJS controller, however I keep getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.

I try to access my carousel through its var attribute from my controller:

```
$scope.myCarousel.on('postchange', function() {
  // do something
});
```

and my carousel is declared in my view:

```
<ons-carousel var="myCarousel" swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll>
...
</ons-carousel>
```

It works, however i can't access the variable myCarousel and can't bind the event to it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched a bit the documentation of ons-carousel and I could overcome this issue by adding `ons-postchange="changeCurrentPictureIndex()"` attribute to my carousel in the view and somehow inside my changeCurrentPictureIndex method I was able to access the myCarousel variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "... and somehow ..." ?

Comment: I was not able to access myCarousel from the controller of the view, however I could access it from the function i bend to the attribute of the ons-carousel. By "... and somehow..." i mean that I don't know the explanation to this.

Answer (score 0):

Use ons.ready function before accessing Carousel variable. Because you can only access variable in controller once onsen initialization is done.

```
ons.ready(function() {
    myCarousel.on('postchange', function(event) {
        //your code
    });
});
```